# unit testing an object that takes a "traits" template parameter

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++03 project where I would like to unit test a class that uses a traits template parameter that exposes static methods (Policy-based design, strategy pattern). I am using Google Test and Google Mock frameworks.

For example:

```
/// the class under test
template< typename FooTraits >
class Foo
{
public:
    void DoSomething()
    {
        FooTraits::handle_type h = FooTraits::Open( "Foo" );
        /* ... */
        FooTraits::Close( h );
    };
};

/// a typical traits structure
struct SomeTraits
{
    typedef HANDLE handle_type;
    static handle_type Open( const char* name ) { /* ... */ };
    static void Close( handle_type h ) { /* ... */ };
};

/// mocked traits that I would like to use for testing
struct MockTraits
{
    typedef int handle_type;
    static MOCK_METHOD1( Open, handle_type( const char* ) );
    static MOCK_METHOD1( Close, void( handle_type ) );
};

/// the test function
TEST( FooTest, VerifyDoSomethingWorks )
{
    Foo< MockTraits > foo_under_test;

    // expect MockTraits::Open is called once
    // expect MockTraits::Close is called once with the parameter returned from Open
    foo_under_test.DoSomething();
};
```

Obviously this won't work as-is. Google Mock can't mock static methods and I would need to create an instance of the Mocked class in the test to set its behavior and expectations.

So what is the correct way to unit test a class that accepts a template policy using Google Test / Google Mock?

Comment: That's kind of genius. Make a singleton class that's mocked and then have the stub reference that. Can you put that in an answer? I want to click the little green check mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you make a class with non-static methods, create a global instance of it (or static in your traits), and have your traits class defer to it?

So, to clarify the idea that was inspired by Rob's comment:

```
struct FunnyDoodad
{
   FunnyDoodad();
   ~FunnyDoodad();

   MOCK_METHOD1( Open, HANDLE( const char* ) );
   MOCK_METHOD1( Close, void( handle_type ) );

};

struct FunnyGlobal {
  FunnyGlobal() : pimpl() {}
  ~FunnyGlobal() { delete pimpl; }

  // You'd want some protection here rather than just dereferencing.
  // it's the whole point.  I'd suggest using whatever unit test assertion
  // mechanism your framework uses and make it a fatal check.    
  handle_type Open(char const* name) { return pimpl->Open(name); }
  void Close(handle_type h) { pimpl->Close(h); }
private:
   FunnyDoodad * pimpl;

  friend struct FunnyDoodad;

  void register(FunnyDoodad* p) { pimpl = p; }
  void deregister() { pimpl = 0; }
};

FunnyGlobal funnyGlobal;

FunnyDoodad::FunnyDoodad() { funnyGlobal.register(this); }
FunnyDoodad::~FunnyDoodad() { funnyGlobal.deregister(); }

struct TestTraits
{
    typedef HANDLE handle_type;
    static handle_type Open( const char* name ) { return funnyGlobal.Open(name); };
    static void Close( handle_type h ) { funnyGlobal.Close(h); };
};

TEST_CASE(blah)
{
   FunnyDoodad testDoodad;

   ...
}
```

I imagine the above could be templated and almost turned into a pattern...maybe.

Comment: You probably wouldn't really want to make the mock instance static or global. The actions of one test might then interfere with the processing of subsequent tests. Instead, have a global or static *pointer* to the trait instance. Declare a local mock trait class in each test, and point the global at it.

Comment: @RobKennedy - I don't know about that.  I can see where you're going, but dereferencing a pointer causes UB.  A screwup in your test could cause who knows what...including passing (if you're particularly unlucky and I can see ways in which it would happen).  Thus I'd suggest something maybe a bit smarter than a pointer.  A static object that's job is to refer to a test-local object that would use RAII like concepts to register/deregister with this thing.  That would probably be the absolute safest way that is sure to be reset per test.